# Java code to write a missing value in a mapping Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a task to take a look in a database (SAP iDoc) that has specific values in it derived by segments. I have to export an xml at the end of the mapping that has a subcomponent that can have more than one row. My problem is that we have a component that has two values that are separated by a qualifier.

Every transaction looks like so:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| QUALF_1  | BETRG_dc  | DOCNUM |
+----------+-----------+--------+
|     001  |        20 | xxxxxx |
|     001  |        22 | xxxxxx |
+----------+-----------+--------+

+---------+-----------+-----------+
| QUALF_2 |  BETRG_pr |  DOCNUM   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|    013  |        30 |    xxxxxx |
|    013  |        40 |    xxxxxx |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

My problem is that when joined with the built in transformations we have a geometrical progression like so

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| DOCNUM  |  BETRG_dc |  BETRG_pr |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| xxxxxx  |        20 |        30 |
| xxxxxx  |        20 |        40 |
| xxxxxx  |        22 |        30 |
| xxxxxx  |        22 |        40 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see only the first and last rows are correct.

The problem comes from the fact that if BETRG_dc is 0 the whole segment is not being sent so a filter transformation fails.

What i found out is the the segment number of QUALF_1 and QUALF_2 are sequencial. So QUALF_1 is for example 48 and QUALF_2 is 49.

Can you help me create a JAVA transformation that adds a row for a missing QUALF_1.

Here is a table of requirements:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
| QUALF | BETRG | SegmentNumber |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   013 |    20 |            48 |
|   001 |   150 |            49 |
|   013 |    15 |            57 |
|   001 |   600 |            58 |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

I want the transformation to take a look and if we have a source like this:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
| QUALF | BETRG | SegmentNumber |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   001 |   150 |            49 |
|   013 |    15 |            57 |
|   001 |   600 |            58 |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

To go ahead and insert a row with the segment id 48 and a value for BETRG of "0".

I have tried every transformation i can.

The expected output should be like this:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
| QUALF | BETRG | SegmentNumber |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   013 |     0 |            48 |
|   001 |   150 |            49 |
|   013 |    15 |            57 |
|   001 |   600 |            58 |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi Alexander and welcome to StackOverflow! Just a tip, you should wrap your tables/code using triple backticks ```, which formats the code as an easily-readable code-block. I also recommend you align and indent any tables/code properly, it makes it easier to read and increases the likelihood you will receive help and reduces the chance you'll be downvoted. The poor formatting is likely the cause of one or more of the downvotes you've received.

Comment: This is fixed now.

Comment: Nice, much better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works:

```
import java.util.*;

private ArrayList<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

QUALF_out = QUALF;
BETRG_out = BETRG;
SegmentNumber_out = SegmentNumber;
DOCNUM = DOCNUM;

array_for_search = QUALF + ParentSegmentNumber + DOCNUM ;
myList2.add(array_for_search);

System.out.println("myList: " + myList2);
System.out.println("Array: " + myList2.contains("910" + ParentSegmentNumber + DOCNUM));

if(!myList2.contains("910" + ParentSegmentNumber + DOCNUM)){
        QUALF_out="910";
        BETRG_out="0";
}
    generateRow();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join both of the table in a joiner transformation.
use Left(master) outer join and then take it into a target. then map the BETRG column from the right table to the target and the rest of the columns from the left table.
what happens is when ever there is no match BETRG will be empty. take it into a expression and see if the value is null or empty and change it to 0 or what value you wish.

Comment: I have to previously filter out QUALF 013 as they are a part of the same data structure. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have created but unfortunately for now it works on a row level only and not on the whole data. I am working on making the code run properly:

```
QUALF_out = QUALF;
BETRG_out= BETRG;
SegmentNumber_out= SegmentNumber;

  if(QUALF.equals("001"))
{
  segment_new=(SegmentNumber - 1);
}

int colCount=1;
myList.add(SegmentNumber);


System.out.println("SegmentNumber_out: " + segment_new);

if(Arrays.asList(myList).contains(segment_new)){
    QUALF_out = QUALF;
    BETRG_out= BETRG;
    SegmentNumber_out= SegmentNumber;    
    QUALF_out="013";
    BETRG_out="0";
    SegmentNumber_out=segment_new;
    generateRow();
    } else {
  QUALF_out = QUALF;
  BETRG_out= BETRG;
  SegmentNumber_out= SegmentNumber;    
  generateRow();
}
```